# Use currently checked value as a itemValue in ListBox

Tags: java, jsf

I have this JSF page:

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="regions">
   <f:selectItem id="eu" value="EU"/>
   <f:selectItem id="us" value="US"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>

<h:selectOneListbox>
    <f:selectItems value="#{dataFetcherBean.regions}" itemLabel="..."/>
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

`dataFetcherBean.regions` is a `HashMap<String, List<String>>` collection. What I want, is to show different data in ListBox depending on what radio button is selected.

Is there a way to get the currently selected value in regions radio buttons to `itemLabel` in the ListBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions :

1 - Use a listener to update your `<h:selectOneListbox>` after the event `onchange` of your `<h:selectOneRadio>`is triggered.

2 - Use `<f:ajax>` if you don't want to reload the full page.

See both here : [SelectOneMenu updates other SelectOneMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533945/selectonemenu-updates-other-selectonemenu)