# Value of <h:selectBooleanCheckbox> is not updated according to backing bean value

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener, selectbooleancheckbox

I'm using JSF2 and Tomcat server. I programmed a simple example in which:

- User Selects a faculty from "h:selectOneMenu"
- Upon selection, the value of "h:inputText" is changed to "odd" or "even" based on facultyNo
- Also, upon selection, the value of "h:selectBooleanCheckBox" is changed to "checked" if facultyNo is even and "not checked" if facultyNo is odd

Everything works fine for "h:inputText". On the other hand, the value of "h:selectBooleanCheckBox" does not change. Why is this happening?

By the way, the use of boolean value inside a HashMap is ***intentional*** because the project I'm working on has lots of boolean values in a HashMap. So, replacing the Hashmap with a simple boolean property and using a getter and a setter for it is definitely not a solution for my case.

The code for the xhtml page is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
     <head>       
        <title>Dummy Title</title>        
     </head>    
     <body>
        <h:form>
            <label for="faculty">Faculty</label>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="faculty" value="#{test.selectedFaculty}" converter="faccon" valueChangeListener="#{test.facultyChange}" onchange="submit()">
                <f:selectItems value="#{start.app.faculties}"/>                      
            </h:selectOneMenu>                                  
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="mycheck" value="#{test.x.get(0)}"></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            <h:outputText value="#{test.res}"></h:outputText>
            <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{test.saveChoices}" />
        </h:form>           
    </body>
</html>
```

The code for the backing bean is below

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import com.myWork.Application;
import com.myWork.Faculty;

@ManagedBean(name="test")
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable
{
    private HashMap<Integer,Boolean> x;
    private String res;
    private Faculty selectedFaculty;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        Application app = Application.getInstance();
        selectedFaculty = app.getFaculties()[0];
        x = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
        if (selectedFaculty.getFacultyNo()%2==0)
        {
            x.put(0, true);
            res = "even";
        }
        else
        {
            x.put(0, false);
            res = "odd";
        }
    }

    public HashMap<Integer,Boolean> getX() {
        return x;
    }


    public void setX(HashMap<Integer,Boolean> x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public Faculty getSelectedFaculty() {
        return selectedFaculty;
    }

    public void setSelectedFaculty(Faculty selectedFaculty) {
        this.selectedFaculty = selectedFaculty;
    }   

    public String getRes() {
        return res;
    }

    public void setRes(String res) {
        this.res = res;
    }

    public void facultyChange(ValueChangeEvent e){
        Faculty fac = (Faculty) e.getNewValue();
        if (fac.getFacultyNo()%2==0)
        {           
            x.put(0, true);
            res = "even";
        }
        else
        {
            x.put(0, false);
            res = "odd";
        }
    }   

    public String saveChoices(){        
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did yo utry to update it from the managedBean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your problem is not related to JSF, it is related to EL. in your case, EL treat you map keys as `long` not `int`, so you should change your map to be:

```
HashMap<Long, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
```

and set the key values as follows :

```
    map.put(0L, false);
    map.put(1L, true);
```

to force it to be auto-boxed to long.

Note: the problem described in detailed in the following question :
[EL access a map value by Integer key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/el-access-a-map-value-by-integer-key)

Answer (score 2):

In order to send updates to a different component, you can make use of partial page rendering by making Ajax calls to send parameters to Managed bean.
Within `<h:selectBooleanCheckBox>`

```
 <h:selectOneMenu id="faculty" value="#{test.selectedFaculty}" converter="faccon" valueChangeListener="#{test.facultyChange}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{start.app.faculties}"/>                      
   </h:selectOneMenu>   

  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="mycheck" valueChangeListener="#{test.facultyChange}" value="#{test.x.get(0)}">
           <f:ajax event="change" execute="@form" render="faculty"/>
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

**Edit:** Removed call to `onSubmit()` in `selectOneMenu`. introduced an ajax call in `selectBooleanCheckbox` for partial page refresh.
Refer full solution at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533945/selectonemenu-updates-other-selectonemenu) post.

Comment: I understand this Akash. However, I need an answer for the particular case in my question. Thanks any way.

Comment: No it does not. The point is when I select a faculty from the menu, the check box should automatically be "checked" or "unchecked" based on the number of the chosen faculty